# MYSQL Joining Tables from Databases on Different Servers

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to use the join operation for two tables from different databases?
Both databases are on different server.Means that How can I select data in the same query from two different databases that are on two different servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`FEDERATED`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) table. There are no other options as far as I know.